# Accessing element with angular set id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have dynamically created elements in my application with the format:

`< div id = "div{{var}}" > ... < / div>`  where var is always an integer.

I see in the page source that it is creating the ids as expected, but the JS selector does not seem to identify it this way. When trying to access these items using jQuery I am struggling to select them by id at all.
An example of this when attempting to select the div with var=1

`$('#div1')` is undefined.

So I was wondering if there is a particular way to access elements by id when they contain angular variables.

Comment: When you inspect the element when the page renders, does it infact have `id="div1"` ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am so confused

Comment: It is ultimately the html that is getting generated in html page. Ideally you should be getting the value in the jQuery method. By $("#id").val().  Please check the structure Once again... May be you get some help

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that the jQuery code is not executed before the ID's are set.

If `$("#div1")` is executed before the div gets the "`div1`" ID then jQuery will return an object with the type "object" instead of "is undefined".
You can test this using this code:

```
console.log("The type is: " + typeof($("#idOfSomethingThatDoesNotExist")));
```

Result:

```
The type is: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `<div id="div{{var}}"> ... </div>`

Instead, you should use `<div ng-attr-id="div{{var}}"> ... </div>`

This ensures that the `id` is only set on the `<div>` once `var` has been evaluated. ie, it is not initially set as `"div{{var}}"` (the literal string).

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind in the future as I am still very new to angular. That did not solve my issue however. The entire div was being dynamically created and apparently I was attempting to access it before it was being written to the dom. I'm not sure what was causing this issue but using a setTimeout() provided a manageable, albeit messy, solution.